# How to fix the value of a key(or macro) when it gets value from another macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfkeys

The following code showes that the value of key `constant` changes with the macro `\aaa`.

My question is: how to fix the value of key `constant` once it gets value from `\aaa` at the first time, so that both `\rule`s give the same rule width(1in here).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\def\aaa{1in}
\pgfkeys{constant/.initial}
\pgfkeys{constant=\aaa}
\rule{\pgfkeysvalueof{/constant}}{5pt}\\
\def\aaa{2in}
\rule{\pgfkeysvalueof{/constant}}{5pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfkeys{constant/.expand once=\aaa}`

Comment: Thank you @muzimuzhi Zso so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted from comment:

`\pgfkeys{constant/.expand once=\aaa}`.

With `\def\aaa{1in}`, the above is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{constant/.expand once=1in}`.